# node JS with different buttons

Tags: node.js

I am playing around making a page and I am trying to have 3 buttons that all do some things similar but add a diffrent "fa fa-tag" when posting to the page.

so if someone clicks the "listing" button after they enter their data with will post it with the "fa fa-flag" and not the "fa fa-tag".
If they click the Buy button it posts a "fa fa-tags"
and Sell would post "fa fa-tag"

.html buttons

```
    <button type="button" id="New_Listing_Button"> Listing </button>

    <button type="button" id="New_sell_Button"> Sell </button>

    <button type="button" id="New_buy_Button"> Buy </button>
```

.HTML data fields

```html
.
```

```
<div id="Popup_Background" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="Dialog_Window" class="hidden">
<div class="Dialog">

  <div class="Window_Header">
    <a href="#"><h3 class="Window_Title"> Yard Sales </h3> </a>
    <button type="button" class="Close_Button">&times;</button>
  </div>

  <div class="Window_body">
    <div class="input_element">
      <label for="text_input">Description</label>
      <textarea id="text_input"><`enter code here`/textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input_element">
      <label for="Date_Input">When Or $ </label>
      <input type="text" id="Date_Input">
    </div>

    <div class="input_element">
      <img for="Img_URL">URL</img>
      <input type="url" id="Img_URL" placeholder="not working">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="Window_Footer">
    <button type="button" class="Window_Cancel_Button">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="Window_Accept_Button">Post</button>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

.nodejs code

```
    app.post('/posts/addListing', function (req, res, next) {
  var posts = postData
  var posting = {

    text: req.body.text,
    amount: req.body.amount,
    imgUrl: req.body.imgUrl,

  };
```

Thank you for any and all help

Comment: What do you mean by "fa fa-tag"? An additional filed in POST request body?

Comment: So if you look at the image [Img](http://imgur.com/a/29fn1) you can see the lay out. when I click list I want to have it add the flag, sell tags, and buy tag in the top left of the post.

Comment: What do you mean by "post"? A record displayed on your web site?